# Sentiment Analysis of given text

Tags: algorithm, sentiment-analysis

This topic has many thread. But also I am posting another one. All the post may be a way to do a sentiment analysis, but I found no way.

I want to implement the doing ways of sentiment analysis. So I would request to show me a way. During my research, I found that [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_spam_filtering) is used anyway. I guess Bayesian algorithm is used to calculate positive words and negative words and calculate the probability of the sentence being positive or negative using bag of words.

This is only for the words, I guess we have to do language processing too. So is there anyone who has more knowledge? If yes, can you guide me with some algorithms with their links for reference so that I can implement. Anything in particular that may help me in my analysis.

Also can you prefer me language that I can work with? Some says Java is comparably time consuming so they don't recommend Java to work with.

Any type of help is much appreciated.

Comment: What's the problem with existing threads about sentiment analysis? There is plenty of both - questions on SO and papers on web about it. Just try out any given approach and ask here **specific questions**, if any.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, sentiment analysis is done on various levels, such as document, sentence, phrase, and feature level. Which one are you working on? There are many different approaches to each of them. You can find a very good intro to this topic [here](http://www.cs.uic.edu/~liub/FBS/Sentiment-Analysis-tutorial-AAAI-2011.pdf). For machine-learning approaches, the most important element is feature engineering and it's not limited to bag of words. You can find many other useful features in different applications from the tutorial I linked. What language processing you need to do depends on what features you want to use. You may need POS-tagging if POS information is needed for your features for example.

For classifiers, you can try Support Vector Machines, Maximum Entropy, and Naive Bayes (probably as a baseline) and these are frequently used in the literature, about which you can also find a pretty comprehensive list in the link. The Mallet toolkit contains ME and NB, and if you use SVMlight, you can easily convert the feature formats to the Mallet format with a function. Of course there are many other implementations of these classifiers.

For rule-based methods, Pointwise Mutual Information is frequently used, and some kinds of scoring-based methods, etc.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For the text analyzing there is no language  stronger than SNOBOL. In SNOBOL-4 the Fortran interpretator, for example, takes only 60 lines.

Answer (score 0):

NLTK offers really good Algorithm for sentiment analysis. It is open source so you can have a look at the source code and check out the algorithm used. You can even download  NLTK book which is free and has some good material on sentiment analysis.

Coming to your second point I dont think Java is that slow. I am myself coding in c++ for years but lately also started with java as if you see a lot of very popular open source softwares like lucene, solr, hadoop, neo4j are all written in java.